# TypeError: Cannot read property 'pause' of underfined - happens only sometimes

Tags: javascript, undefined, typeerror, pause

I know what this error means in general. If I had 'pause' (or 'play') variables in my code not set by the time of execution, I would probably get this error. The strange thing is I have no clue where those variables come from. I am getting this error only on one PC (other 2 PCs I've tested seem completely OK) and the errors block the rest of my code.

At first it seemed to me some Chrome extension is causing the error, but I am getting the same error on Edge as well. Sometimes it works (even on the mentioned problematic PC).

[image]

What could be the issue?

Comment: It's one of your extensions code

Comment: can you share the code?

Comment: @JuanCarrey but as I mentioned, happens on various browsers

Comment: @YatendrasinhJoddha I'd be glad to, but what code? I didn't write anything related to those errors. Apart from that, it is a back-end page of WordPress that runs a simple AJAX call on button click, but it is really simple, straightforward and as I said, works perfectly on other machines and is not related to those errors.

Comment: You can have the same extension installed on the two browsers still.

It can not be a back-end page, it has to be a front-end page which runs the AJAX call.

Where does the ajax call goes to ? (host)

Sometimes, some installed applications install extensions on all your browsers, and modify a bunch of default settings for you automatically, that can cause these kind of problems.